# Inserting a DOM element in more than one location with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some pagination code defined in a variable ($pager) that I would like to appear at the top **and** bottom of a table ($table).

I've tried the following:

```
$pager.
 insertBefore($table);
 insertAfter($table);
```

However, the second instruction appears to overwrite the first, meaning the pages only appear beneath the table. How can I insert the pagination at the top and bottom of the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [`clone`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/clone) your pager object, but be careful with your markup, since you could end up having duplicated id attributes:

```
$pager.insertBefore($table).clone().insertAfter($table);
```

And if you want to clone also and all their event handlers, use [clone(true)](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/clone#bool).

Answer (score 0):

i think if you put a .clone() in there it might work...